# Creating an iOS app that communicates with Windows

Tags: ios, windows

I'm looking to create an iOS app that communicates with a Windows app (also made by me). I've created some basic iOS apps in the past but I'm looking for assistance on the specifics of communicating with a Windows device.

Much like how a "remote mouse" application would work (where you install an iOS app and download the partnered Windows installer, which then talk together) I am looking to have my app search and then communicate with a program installed on a local network.

Is there a framework or recommended path to take when designing an app of this kind? The app itself will simply relay information available to the program installed in Windows as a proof of concept and then extra functionality will be added later. I'm primarily focusing on creating a working foundation where the iOS app and Windows program speak over the LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented something similar to what you are describing using TCP sockets. Socket is a stream of raw bytes, after establishing a connection successfully between two ends, a socket may send or receive some bytes, there is no specific logical rules to define what you are sending or receiving, these bytes could represent anything, that is, you must define your protocol or structure of messages you are sending and receiving within your code logic to have meaningful messages at the end.

For example of a simple protocol, if you want to send a message (that message could be string, integer or anything) you send four bytes that represents an integer which specify the size of actual message (which has been serialized to bytes), then you send the actual message bytes, at the other end you read four bytes, which you know that they are representing the actual message size, now you know that you are expecting a specific number of bytes which represents a full message, so you keep reading bytes until you get all of these bytes to have a valid message. After receiving a message, you wait for another four bytes which represents new message size, and so on.

The message itself could be any serializable data type. Most programming languages supports serializing primitive types by default, if you want to serialize custom data type, one option is to encode your message (which, for example, is an instance of a struct that conforms to Codable protocol) using Swift JSONEncoder, so at the other end you expect a JSON bytes, which you can then decode them back to the original object. Another good option to serialize structured data is [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

You may have a look at [this class](https://github.com/AhmedOS/Connect-4-Ultimate/blob/master/src/connect4/Connection.cs) written in C#, it is a similar implementation of what I have described here, it is a bit different, but you will get the idea.

Note: default bytes order (endianness) may differ depending on the platform and programming language, it could be little-endian or big-endian.

[CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) is a good library for dealing with sockets in iOS.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for the detailed response and links!